# Google Plus button: selecting different languages

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-plus-one

The code below is for the Google Plus button in Español

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {lang: 'es'}
</script>
```

I also use "English" and "Deutsch" languages in my website. How do I add these languages {lang: 'en'} and {lang: 'de'} to the above code using if statement or a switch statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mozilla has a good overview of [switch statements in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)